# Apache Directory adding partition programmatically

Tags: apache, ldap, apacheds

I'm trying to create a partition programmatically. I've tried following the example on the ApacheDS website (https://directory.apache.org/apacheds/basic-ug/1.4.3-adding-partition.html#adding-a-partition-programmatically) , but this example is definitely not correct.

Here is my code:

```
LdapConnection connection = new LdapNetworkConnection(host, port);     
connection.bind(admin, password);

connection.loadSchema();
SchemaManager schemaManager = connection.getSchemaManager();
Dn suffixDn = new Dn(schemaManager, "dc=newParition,dc=com");

JdbmPartition newPartition = new JdbmPartition(schemaManager);
newPartition.setId("newParition");
newPartition.setSuffixDn(suffixDn);
newPartition.setCacheSize(1000);
newPartition.setPartitionPath(new URI("file:///var/lib/apacheds-2.0.0-M15/default/partitions/newParition"));

newPartition.addIndex(new JdbmIndex("objectClass", false));
newPartition.addIndex(new JdbmIndex("dc", false));

Entry contextEntry = new DefaultEntry(schemaManager, suffixDn);
contextEntry.put("objectClass", "domain", "top");
contextEntry.put("dc", "newParition");

newPartition.initialize();
newPartition.add(new AddOperationContext(null, contextEntry));
```

I'm seeing the following error when I try to add the contextEntry to the partition:

```
org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.exception.LdapSchemaViolationException: ERR_219 Entry dc=newParition,dc=com contains no entryCsn attribute: Entry …
```

It doesn't even look like the partition is being added to my server (when I restart my apacheds server, I don't see any new namingContexts under the Root DSE). I think I'm missing some steps here, but not sure what they are.

Comment: I am getting same error? Did you find any solution..Did you find any method to create partition using code....Please post solution

Answer (score -1):

An advice from the Apache DS dev's mailing list:

"// ALWAYS add an entry using CoreSession's API". Check http://apaste.info/KHX for a nearly complete example of how to add a partition. The missing class EmbeddedServer is as follows:

```
 private static final class EmbeddedServer {
    private DirectoryService directoryService;
    private LdapServer ldapService;

    public EmbeddedServer(final String host, final int port) throws Exception {
        init(host, port);
    }

    private void init(final String host, final int port) throws Exception {

        DefaultDirectoryServiceFactory factory = new DefaultDirectoryServiceFactory();
        factory.init("Test");
        this.directoryService = factory.getDirectoryService();
        this.directoryService.getChangeLog().setEnabled(false);
        this.directoryService.setShutdownHookEnabled(true);
        this.directoryService.setInstanceLayout(new InstanceLayout("/tmp/ldapServer"));

        this.ldapService = new LdapServer();
        this.ldapService.setTransports(new TcpTransport(host, port));
        this.ldapService.setDirectoryService(this.directoryService);
    }

    public void start() throws Exception {

        this.directoryService.startup();
        this.ldapService.start();
    }

    public void stop() throws Exception {

        this.ldapService.stop();
        this.directoryService.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: The paste has expired making this answer unusable.

Comment: Damn, the paste was not provided by me. Unfortunately I can not provide an alternative.